# Classist Unit Testing - Avoiding Mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, refactoring, mediatr

I am trying to follow the Classist approach for Unit Testing. I try to only mock external dependencies (external API, file system, etc...). I try to separate data access code (EF Core) from core domain classes, allowing me to test those core classes without those dependencies.

In the following class:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Cornerstone.Services;
using MediatR;
using Cornerstone.Entities.Cornerstone.Actions.LDAP;
using Cornerstone.Entities.Cornerstone.Actions;

namespace Cornerstone.Features.Actions.ActionExecuters
{
    public class AddUserActionExecuter : IActionExecuter
    {
        private readonly LdapService ldapService;
        private readonly AddUserAction action;
        private readonly IMediator mediator;

        public AddUserActionExecuter(LdapService ldapService, AddUserAction action, IMediator mediator)
        {
            this.ldapService = ldapService ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(ldapService));
            this.action = action ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(action));
            this.mediator = mediator;
        }

        public async Task<bool> CanExecute()
        {
            var sourceContact = await mediator.Send(new GetContactForActionQuery(action));
            return !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(action.SamAccountName) 
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(action.Email) 
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceContact.FirstName) 
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(sourceContact.Surname) 
                && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(action.Ou) 
                && action.Groups.Count > 0;
        }

        public async Task<ExecutionResult> Execute()
        {
            var sourceContact = await mediator.Send(new GetContactForActionQuery(action));
            ldapService.CreateUserAccount(action.Ou, action.SamAccountName, action.Password, action.UniqueCN, action.Email,  sourceContact.FirstName, sourceContact.Surname, action.Email);
            ldapService.AddUserToGroups(action.SamAccountName, action.Groups.ToArray());
            return new ExecutionResult { Successful = true };
        }

    }
}
```

you can see that I am using MediatR to send queries. Using MediatR, I am fetching a Contact that corresponds to a `SourceContactId` property on the `AddUserAction` class.

If I want to unit test the logic in the `CanExecute` method, I can see two choices:

1. Mock the MediatR handler and make it return a contact I prepared
2. Create a new class like `AddAdUserActionExecuter_Helper` that has a method `bool CheckCanExecute(AddUserAction action, Contact contact)` and move the logic there, then I would call this from the original `CanExecute` and unit test only the new method which now has no dependency on MediatR.

**My question is**: in number 2 which may be the option more inline with my design choices,  given that there is only one user for this introduced method, doesn't it seem like we're adding a new class and exposing its method just for the sake of testing?

Comment: If you create `AddAdUserActionExecuter_Helper` class, will it not use mediator? How will you unit test `AddAdUserActionExecuter_Helper ` ? What's the issue with mocking the behavior of `mediator.Send` method?

Comment: The behaviour I am trying to test here is in the return statement in `CanExecute`, tests for other units (like the MediatR handler) would have not much logic in them and would possibly be covered in Integration tests.

Comment: 1 is the way to go. Number 2 limits you in that you are not testing the actual code run in production, so if anything changes wiring it your tests won't catch it.

Comment: what about my question @zaitsman?

Comment: @3m3sd1 the answer is 'yes it does seem like you're addign a class just for the sake of testing'. This is why 2 is not a good design

Comment: Did you try implementing Option2 and see if it actually fix the issue you are facing?

Comment: @zaitsman but doesn't option 1 go against the classist approach?

Comment: @3m3sd1 Maybe? I've no idea why you're so hang up on that. Software is written to be useful, maintainable and purposeful. Moving logic out coz you're afraid of mocks is neither and has a risk of you breaking things for users of your app because you wanted to follow some 'approach'. At the end of the day, it's your call

Comment: Also not much point fetching `sourceContact` if `action` has any blank values.